# Sorting a matrix and placing it in one row

Tags: opencv

I am trying to figure a way of sorting a 3x3 row into a 9x1.

So i have following:

[image]

I want to end up with this:

[image]

This is what i end up doing so far:

```
            Rect roi(y-1,x-1,kernel,kernel);
            Mat image_roi = image(roi);
            Mat image_sort(kernel, kernel, CV_8U);
            cv::sort(image_roi, image_sort, CV_SORT_ASCENDING+CV_SORT_EVERY_ROW);
```

The code is not functional, currently i cannot find any data in my image_sort after its "sorted".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you have single-channel grey level images? Try:

```
cv::Mat image_sort = cv::Mat::zeros(rect.height, rect.width, rect.type()); // allocated memory
image(roi).copyTo(image_sort); // copy data in image_sorted
std::sort(image_sort.data, image_sort.dataend); // call std::sort
cv::Mat vectorized = image_sort.reshape(1, 1); // reshaped your WxH matrix into a 1x(W*H) vector.
```